# Function to get stored callback

Tags: c, function, callback

Suppose I have a variable, that stores the callback.

```
void* (*function)(int, double);
```

Now I would like to create a function, that will return this callback. I do not want the user to access the callback directly but by a function. This doesn't work:

```
void* (*)(int, double) getCallback();
```

My question is: What will the prototype for such function look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typedef` the callback type:

```
typedef void* (*pf)(int, double);

pf getCallback();
```

This will also make sure that there are no mistakes from manually typing the wrong signature and such.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the direct syntax for this is

```
void* (*getCallback())(int, double);
```

But probably better and more readable would be to use a typedef:

```
typedef void* (*CallbackFunc)(int, double);

CallbackFunc getCallback();
```

Comment: Hm, the typedef is OK, but using the raw method doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Melon I think it's `void *(*getCallback())(int, double);`